# 'LinkList' does not name a type

Tags: c++, oop

I declared a class in another file named LinkedList. Now when I try to run my code, on the line where I declared the object of LinkedList, the compiler gives me the error of **'LinkedList' does not name a Type**.
my code is this

```
using namespace std;

struct BstNode{
    int data;
    BstNode *left,*right,*parent;
};

class BinarySearch{
public:
    BstNode *root,*leaf;
    LinkedList link;//here comes the error

public:
    BinarySearch(){
    root=NULL;
    leaf=NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Well, what is `LinkedList`? There is no such class in your code.

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: well I defined it in another file.

Comment: You must include the header file it was defined in, using the preprocessor `#include`

Comment: @MunibShah You might want to tell the compiler that!

Comment: sorry But I don't know how to add a custom header file....
but both files are in same directory

Comment: I would highly recommend a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: You need to put `#include "linked_list.h"` (replace with your header files name) at the beginning of the shown file. If that is not solving your problem, please post the complete code (of all files) in the form of a [repro] in your question, so we don't have to guess what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have this included in your file already, `#include "LinkedList.h"` is needed in order to include your class from a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

You must include the file that contains the declaration of LinkedList in the file that contains what you show above.

Failure to do so will result in a compiler error as the compiler has no way of knowing what LinkedList is.

So use the preprocessor directive #include to achieve that:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
```